# 000webhost not retrieving/fetching data from database,some buttons and error message doesn't work,but in localhost it works

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm sure I have the right connection towards 000webhost.

```
   <?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost","***","****","****");
if($db->connect_error){
    connection error :(";
}
```

This is my code for fetching data inside my table

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM movie");

$data = "";
while($r = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if ($data != "") {$data .= ",";}
    $data .= '{"movieid":"'  . $r->movieid . '",';
    $data .= '"moviename":"'   . $r->moviename . '",';
    $data .= '"director":"'   . $r->director . '",';
    $data .= '"cast1":"'   . $r->cast1 . '",';
    $data .= '"genre":"'. $r->genre . '"}'; 
    }
    $result->free();
$data ='{"records":['.$data.']}';
$db->close();
echo($data);
```

And this is the table on where the results will show

```
 <tbody ng-init="getall()">
     <tr ng-repeat="d in names | filter:search">
    <td>{{ d.movieid }}</td>
    <td>{{ d.moviename }}</td>
    <td>{{ d.director }}</td>
    <td>{{ d.cast1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ d.genre }}</td>
    <td><a href="#" ng-click="edituser(d.movieid)">Edit</a> | <a href="" ng-click="deleteuser(d.movieid)">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the result:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZkqj.png basically it is just showing the name of my textfields instead of the data.Some of my buttons also don't work,and an error message if the fields are left blank don't show up.
However,on my PHPAdmin XAMPP localhost,I can see the data inside my table successfully retrieved.

Comment: is the server you made on 000host is angular or node compatible ?

Comment: does your console log anything on the server?

Comment: it  does not show any errors

Comment: the files is properly named .php?

Comment: yes,they are named as .php,i also tried removing my javascript,still the same output